# Merging a dummy variable DataFrame to other dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a DataFrame in python named `dummy` and want to merge it to the starting columns. I have written the following:

```
df=df.merge(dummy, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

But it is adding dummy in the end. How to merge it to the starting?

Comment: Please, provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you mean you just want to reverse the merge order? `dummy.merge(df...)` ?

Comment: Or reindex you colums afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply merge df to dummy and not the other way around.

```
df=dummy.merge(df,left_index=True,right_index=True)
```